Open browser extension popup with different arguments
In manifest.json I have defined:
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "128": "img/icon128.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Grasshopper",
        "default_popup": "main.html"
    },

And:
        "_execute_browser_action": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Ctrl+Space"
            },
            "description": "Toggle the popup"
        },

Which launches the popup. But I want to try opening it with different arguments, so it does something different at launch. Have multiple of these. Is this possible? Maybe some custom call to main.html?something=true ? I don't see how to do it.

There's no way to provide parameters when the popup is opened via a hotkey. You can suggest it in WECG.
